# Bootstrap 3 search box not bringing up any results

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, search, search-box

I added a search box to my Bootstrap 3 site but if try searching for something it doesn't pull up any results, it just refreshes the page you are on:

[see this](http://www.dawaf.co.uk/creative-mapping/)

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

I thought it was because I didn't have a search.php file but I am still experiencing the same problem once I added it.

search.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Search Results pages
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Wp_Bootstrap
 * @since Wp Bootstrap 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'wpbootstrap' ), get_search_query() ); ?></h1>
            </header>

            <?php /* The loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php wpbootstrap_paging_nav(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Does your site run on Wordpress?

Comment: Yes it does run on Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

your form `<form class="navbar-form" role="search">` tag didn't contain an action and you need to give the input text a name

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search" action="<?php esc_url( site_url() ) ?>" method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
       <input name="s" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

Comment: I added that but now it takes you to Page not found if you try and search for anything.

Comment: @user3050023 put the path to your search.php page such as "pages/somefolders/search.php"

Comment: I added the path but it is just bringing up a white screen

Comment: I'm still getting the white screen. Is the above code to replace what's in the search.php file or be added to it?

Comment: @user3050023 yes, try it

Comment: @user3050023 ok restore your search.php and update your html with the edited answer again

Comment: When you are on the Home page you can search but it doesn't bring up any search results but if you search on other pages it says page not found. Strangely if you search when you are on the Toolbox page it refreshes it.

Comment: try to replace home_url with site_url

Comment: Still having the same problem.

Comment: i think this problem because you are working under a subdomain so  change action to action="http://www.dawaf.co.uk/creative-mapping/" should solve this problem

Comment: Sorry but it hasn't fixed the problem.

Comment: sorry the link parsed, add the full url including the http:// 
"http:// www. dawaf.co.uk/creative-mapping/" without the spaces

Comment: Made progress in the sense that it now takes you to the search results page but same problem in that no results are displaying.

Comment: i think no results because you don't have posts

Comment: I do have posts set up. I tried searching for the word 'lorem' which is used on posts and pages on the site but nothing appears in the results.

Comment: try * will bring results, so it seem you have a problem with your content
http:// www. dawaf.co.uk/creative-mapping/?s=*

Comment: I'm baffled as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

This code may work for you

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" action="search.php" method="get">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="s" value="<?php $_GET['s']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="search...">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
</form>
```

Understanding

in the parameter **action** you need to put the path of your file **search.php**

On **input type** you need to add the parameter **name** this is the parameter that you are using to search which is **s**

Next you need to add the value parameter and add this `<?php $_GET['s']; ?>`

You are done, test this code and tell if this work for you.

Try whit this **Updated Code**

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="s" value="<?php $_GET['s']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php _e('Search', 'wpbootstrap'); ?>">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
    </form>
```

Comment: It's still not working correctly. If you search it brings up a white screen.

Comment: It takes you to the results page but doesn't display any results.

Answer (score 0):

I share here personal experience.

Please aknowledge that the code I share here is not ready for your Theme, as you should [at least] change the textdomain from

```
minimax3
```

to

```
your_text_domain
```

The search form works if you set the search form up like this:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" method="get">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="s" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php _e('Search', 'minimax3'); ?>">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

Note that there is no need to add the value parameter as this

```
<?php $_GET['s']; ?>
```

Note that I have a search.php in my Theme's Root Folder as this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div id="primary" class="col-lg-9 col-md-9">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <header class="page-header">
                    <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'minimax3' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
                </header><!-- .page-header -->

                <?php minimax3_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

                <!--Start the Loop-->
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'search' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php minimax3_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

                <br>

                <!--Inlcude the search form at the bottom-->
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="primary" class="col-lg-9 col-md-9">
                            <h3><?php _e( 'Not what you were looking for?', 'minimax3' ); ?></h3>
                            <p><?php _e( 'Refine your search below!', 'minimax3' ); ?></p>
                            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--If no results-->
                <?php else : ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'search' ); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
</section><!-- #primary .content-area -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

If you still get "white pages" (WPOD) you might need ot turn on the WP Debug Constante liek this below in your wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

Tell us then the errors you will see on your screen
That can help ;)